# Can prawns and lobsters live out of water for more than six hours?

Tags: invertebrates

I live in Telangana which is a state of India.I like eating Non-vegetarian food.People of our state eat pond fish more comparing to other aquafood.In many places near me,I've seen people cutting alive fishes in to pieces with their big knives.I won't feel good to see this.So,usually I bring the pond fishes home and keep them aside for atleast 40 minutes with no water in contact to them.In these 40 minutes I prepare other ingredients needed for the recipe.After these 40 minutes,generally as there is no response from those fishes I start cutting them into pieces.In the same way I don't know how much time it will take for prawns and lobsters to die without water.Do they live more than six hours without water?

This question is not related to the experiments carried out by the biologists on lab creatures.They are great people.I encourage their experiments whether it involves humane killing or inhumane killing because their experiments on one creature may help millions of remaining creatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** version is they are [gill breathers](https://www.wordnik.com/words/gill-breather) and need to be in a humid and moist environment to have a considerable longer life span outside sea water.

**Dr. Cowan**'s on being asked the same question about lobster said:

> “Gills work best in seawater, but if lobsters are kept in containers of seawater with no aeration, they quickly use up the oxygen and suffocate,” she said. “That it why it is imperative to transport lobsters in containers with no standing water.” - *New York Times*

Many lobsters, shrimps and even crayfish & crabs are [transported in boxes with a small amount of water in the bottom and they survive for several days like that](https://www.seafish.org/media/Publications/CrustaceaGPG_0505.pdf). However the long term side effects of this are still to be discovered as most crustaceans transported this way get cooked.